# Build List of missing values by scanning multiple collections

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have multiple time series (Example below). I need to scan these multiple lists and build a list of missing values. Can someone advise an approach please?

```
public class TimeSeries
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }    

        public double Value { get; set; }   
    }
```

I have 3 lists (condensed into the table below); each series would have the same datetime & it's value. So gp1Series will have datetime and value1, gp2Series will have the same datetime and value2 annd gp3Series will have the same datetime and value3.

```
Date            Value1  Value2  Value3
30/01/2014 23:00    748 -1  1
30/01/2014 23:30    747 1   1
31/01/2014 00:00    746 1   1
31/01/2014 00:30    745 1   1
31/01/2014 01:00    745 1   1
31/01/2014 01:30    744 1   1
31/01/2014 02:00    743 1   1
31/01/2014 02:30    0   0   0
31/01/2014 03:00    743 1   1
31/01/2014 03:30    742 1   1
31/01/2014 04:00    741 1   1
31/01/2014 04:30    740 1   1
31/01/2014 05:00    0   0   1
```

Only if all 3 values for the same datetime have value 0 do I need to add them into a new list.  So, in the above example 31/01/2014 2:30 will need to be added to the new list since all the lists have value 0. However 31/01/2014 05:00 will not need to be added to the new list since value3 is non zero.

Any recommendations please?

Comment: i would suggest a union of the 3 lists, then group on the `Date` and do a `Count` where the Value in each grouping ==0. i would add an answer, but am traveling and am adding via phone. hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get DateTime which has zero values in all three lists:

```
from v1 in gp1Series
join v2 in gp2Series on v1.DateTime equals v2.DateTime
join v3 in gp3Series on v2.DateTime equals v3.DateTime
where v1.Value == 0 && v2.Value == 0 && v3.Value == 0
select v1.DateTime
```

Another approach (inspired by @jim)

```
gp1Series.Where(ts => ts.Value == 0)
         .Concat(gp2Series.Where(ts => ts.Value == 0))
         .Concat(gp3Series.Where(ts => ts.Value == 0))
         .GroupBy(ts => ts.DateTime)
         .Where(g => g.Count() == 3)
         .Select(g => g.Key)
```

If you need `TimeSeries` instances, you can select `new { v1, v2, v3 }` in first case, or simply remove projection in second case.

Comment: +1 sergey, this is `there or thereabouts` re how i'd have approached it :-)